# MergeSort Vs NLogN curve (Python) (Not getting the expected Graph)

Tags: python, matplotlib, graph, time-complexity, mergesort

I am trying to plot a graph between the execution time of merge sort for sorting n elements vs nlogn but I am not getting the expected graph.

```
from random import randint
from math import log2
import timeit
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


def merge(arr, l, m, r):
    n1 = m - l + 1
    n2 = r - m
    L = [0] * (n1)
    R = [0] * (n2)
    for i in range(0, n1):
        L[i] = arr[l + i]
    for j in range(0, n2):
        R[j] = arr[m + 1 + j]

    i = 0    # Initial index of first subarray
    j = 0    # Initial index of second subarray
    k = l    # Initial index of merged subarray

    while i < n1 and j < n2:
        if L[i] <= R[j]:
            arr[k] = L[i]
            i += 1
        else:
            arr[k] = R[j]
            j += 1
        k += 1

    # Copy the remaining elements
    while i < n1:
        arr[k] = L[i]
        i += 1
        k += 1

    # Copy the remaining elements
    while j < n2:
        arr[k] = R[j]
        j += 1
        k += 1


def mergeSort(arr, l, r):
    if l < r:
        m = l+(r-l)//2
        mergeSort(arr, l, m)
        mergeSort(arr, m+1, r)
        merge(arr, l, m, r)


arr = []
x = []
y = []
n = []
for i in range(1, 3000, 100):
    for j in range(i):
        temp = randint(0, i)
        arr.append(temp) # making a array of random int values
    x.append(i)
    start = timeit.default_timer()
    mergeSort(arr, 0, i-1)
    end = timeit.default_timer()
    y.append(end - start) # storing the execution time to sort the array
    n.append(i*log2(i)) # Calculating nlogn

plt.plot(x, y, label='merge sort')
plt.plot(x, n, label='nlogn')
plt.legend()
plt.xlabel('array size ')
plt.ylabel('execution time (s)')
plt.title('Merge Sort')
plt.show()
```

Output of this program:

[image]

Excepted output:

[image]

As we know that the time complexity of merge sort algorithm is O(nlogn), but when i am trying to plot it it's very low.

Please suggest me a method to plot the graphs or some modification in this code.

Comment: college project? you ll never get expected graph for such small datasets, because various things come into play one suh factor is CPU caching

Comment: @HimanshuPoddar, no it's not a college project. Can you explain me more about it or is there any other way to do the same thing ?

Comment: please try with atleast dataset of sizes greater than 500, 000 with random generated data

Comment: @HimanshuPoddar I have already tried that, still got the same result.

Comment: yeah, more data would mean more improvisation from the os

Answer (score 0):

Differences in time for small arrays will be affected by the level of cache a small array fits into. Even for large arrays, cache will affect sort times as opposed to counting the number of operations (compares and moves). There's also the overhead of Python, over 50 times as slow as a C or C++ implementation for the same merge sort algorithm. For large n, the number of operations approaches O(n), since log2(2n)/log2(n) approaches 1. For example log2(2^11) / log2(2^10) = 1.10, log2(2^21) / log2(2^20) = 1.05, log2(2^26) / log2(2^25) = 1.04, and so on.

Comment: So, is there any other way to calculate the execution time, and plot the graph to get the expected output?

Comment: @AnshumanSharma - the issue is that as size grows within a range of a power of 2, such as 2^p <= n < 2^(p+1), the number of operations grows linearly, by O(n), until n >= 2^(p+1), at which point there is the equivalent of a bottom up merge sort making (p+1)/(p) passes. You could count the number of operations instead of time for n = smaller powers of 2, to get something that looks like n log(n) graph.